# Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in

Tags: php

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Não consigo identificar qual é o meu error**

esta marcado a linha no codigo,

```html
   O ERRRO ESTAR AQUI ->[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1] if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado)>0) {
      $password = md5($password);

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$login' OR email = '$login'";

      $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
      //$_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $dados['id'];
        if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) == 1){

          mysqli_close($conexao);
          $dados = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
          $_SESSION['logado'] = true;

          $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $dados['id'];
         echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Login e senha confirmado</div>";
          header('location:../../../index.php');
 

        }else{
          $erros[] = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Usuario Inexistente</div>";
          

        }
    }
```

Comment: Isso acontece pois o retorno da função `mysqli_query` é `false` ou `null`. Utilize um `if (!$resultado) { die('Not found'); }` antes da função `mysqli_num_rows`

Comment: Tente trocar o ````if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) == 1){```` por  ```if($resultado->num_rows == 1){``` e vê se corrige.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr o erro persiste,

Comment: @Luiz Fernando, o erro persiste tambem

Comment: @ValdeirPsr poste seu código atualizado em http://pastebin.com

Comment: ok, aqui esta de forma atualizada https://pastebin.com/Z1QB22zw

Comment: https://pastebin.com/JzXcpmEk

Comment: infelizmente nao funcionou